# Json format in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, json.net

I'm trying to create a json string of the following format in WP8

> {"user": { "email": "abc@gmail.me", "password": "abc"}}

I have created `{ "email": "abc@gmail.me", "password": "abc*"}` part like

```
        string emailText = confirmEmailTbox.Text;
        string passText = "password";
        string pass = confirmPasswordPBox.Password;

        Dictionary<string, string> jsonChild = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        jsonChild.Add(emailText, email);
        jsonChild.Add(passText, pass);
        string jsonStringChild = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonChild, Formatting.None);
```

But how do i put all this into the other object as in how do i add the "user" to the 
jsonString

**Edit**: Both formats

```
{
"user": {
  "email": "abc@gmail.me"
  "password": "12345"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leverage the anonymous objects available in C#:

```
 var data = new { user = new { email=email, password = pass}};
 string jsonStringChild = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Comment: How do deserialize email and password from this?

Comment: using JSON.net, you can use var j = JObject.Parse(jsonStringChild) and then email would be j.SelectToken("user").SelectToken("email") and password accordingly.